# Webp src (for WebP Express)

Tags: wordpress

I use WebP Express plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/webp-express/).

Coould you tell me how to get a path to webp image.

I mean an analogue to this:

```
wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment_id = 1, $size = 'medium_large');
```

And the result should be something like

http://galina/wp-content/webp-express/webp-images/uploads/2019/12/sports-4-768x512.jpg.webp

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a class in order to fix this.

```
use \WebPExpress\AlterHtmlHelper;

class WebpExpressExtended
{
    public static function background($imgId, $imgSize = 'full')
    {
        $img = wp_get_attachment_image_src($imgId, $imgSize)[0];
        if (!$imgId || !$img) {
            return false;
        }
        return AlterHtmlHelper::getWebPUrl($img, null);
    }
}
```

Paste it on functions.php or in some file required there.

To use it just call the static method background($imageID, $imageSize);

```
echo WebpExpressExtended::background(309, 'thumbnail');
```